# What to change in product list button to allow "View Details" instead of "Add to Cart"?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, product-list

I'm looking to use a "View Details" button instead of add to cart because the latter isn't always working with my Full Page Cache extension (it instead just shows you that your cart is empty when you try to add something), so for now, until I find a fix, I would like to use "View Details" as it should work all the time.

What method would I use within the `<button onclick="">` so that it links to the item's details?

Here is the current code in my template file:

```
<p>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">
        <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span>
    </button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details')?></a>
```

Where `$_product` is the current product you are displaying.

If you want to use a button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('View Details')?></button>
```

Comment: Also, j/w which class is `getProductUrl()` in?

Comment: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`